# Help with what to bake leftover cake batter in

Tags: baking, cake, recipe-scaling

I have a Jubliee bundt pan that is only 10 cups, but my recipe is for a bundt pan at least 12 cups.  I've only made the recipe once and it turned out great.  But since I insisted in using as much of the batter as would fit in the pan, it overflowed while baking.  I cut the overflow off and ate it separately, but I'd like to make it next time where it doesn't overflow.  Since the recipe uses a box mix as the base and alters the ingredients you add, it's not a good idea to cut the recipe by 1/4 (not only would I have to figure out what 3/4 of the box mix would be, I'd have to use 3/4 of an egg!).  My thought is to make the batter and the filling but only use 3/4 of it for the bundt pan.  Any thoughts on what size pan or how many cupcakes I could make with the remaining batter?  You can find the recipe here:  http://allrecipes.com/recipe/chocolate-irish-car-bomb-cake/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this for 'left-over' batter, or a whole batch:

**An Ice Cream Cone:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use a muffin tin (cupcake pan).  The upside is that you don't need to know in advance how many you will get.  Just keep scooping until you run out, filling each cup about 3/4 full.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of crown you want on your cupcakes, you generally fill them 1/2 to 3/4 full.  As muffin tins come in different sizes, you'd have to measure your pans to determine how many cupcakes that would be for your pans.

Answer (score 1):

Another great idea I have seen is to cook cake batter in a waffle iron.